# Why does my class only return the first value?

Tags: php, class, function

This Class gives me a blank output even if I change return to echo, I'm not sure what the issue is but I'm obviously not that versed in dealing with Classes and Objects.

I'm sure I'm just handling the variables/arrays incorrectly, but I can't see where, maybe the variables shouldn't be declared under `Class` since they should only be returned if a person is created? Should I declare variables in the function, or not declare them at all since they should be handled by `$args`?

**Updated Question:** How do I get it to return every argument not just FIRSTNAME?

PHP:

```
class people_handler
{
    public $firstname;
    public $middlename;
    public $lastname;
    public $city;
    public $province_state;
    /* zip+4 is default for postcode (postal code) */
    public $postcode;
    public $country;

    function create_people($args)
    {
        $fullname=array($this->firstname,$this->middlename,$this->lastname);
        $normname=array($this->firstname,$this->lastname);
        $fulladdress=array($this->city,$this->province_state,$this->postcode,$this->country);
        if(!$args->middlename&&$args->firstname && $args->lastname && $args->city && $args->province_state && $args->postcode && $args->country)
        {
            $temp_arr=array($normname,$fulladdress);
            foreach($temp_arr as $value)
            {
                foreach($value as $values)
                {
                    return $values;
                }
            }
        }
        else if($args->firstname && $args->middlename && $args->lastname && $args->city && $args->province_state && $args->postcode && $args->country)
        {
            $temp_arr=array($fullname,$fulladdress);
            foreach($temp_arr as $value)
            {
                foreach($value as $values)
                {
                    return $values;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            die ("Must enter all values excluding middlename.");
        }
    }
}

$p1=new people_handler;
$p1->firstname="John";
$p1->middlename="Jonah";
$p1->lastname="Jameson";
$p1->city="Lansing";
$p1->province_state="Michigan";
$p1->postcode="48876-4444";
$p1->country="USA";


echo $p1->create_people($p1);
```

Returns:

```
John
```

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @mgraph: That doesn't matter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the Object self-reference: `$this` all over the place.

Anytime you refer to a method or property from within the class, you need to refer to $this as the current instantiation of the Object that is doing the process. So, for instance...

```
$fullname=array($firstname,$middlename,$lastname);
```

becomes

```
 $fullname=array($this->firstname,$this->middlename,$this->lastname);
```

Which should work, since you assigned the values to those properties already.

EDIT: Looking at the code further, constantly returning a value through loops won't manage the echoing to the browser. You can either `echo $value` instead of returning it, or build an array from the values and return that and have the script handle the array to echo to the browser.

EDIT THE SECOND: To get all the values out, you need to collect them as you build them. Another option is to simply output them to the browser as part of the method. Both options work, but collecting them into an array makes it more portable, but also a fair bit more code to maintain. As well, you do not need to pass the object into itself to get the method to work.

```
echo $p1->create_people($p1);
```

Should be...

```
$p1->create_people();
```

In `create_people` you'll have...

```
function create_people()
{
    $fullname=array($this->firstname,$this->middlename,$this->lastname);
    $normname=array($this->firstname,$this->lastname);
    $fulladdress=array($this->city, $this->province_state, $this->postcode, $this->country);
    if($args->firstname && $args->lastname && $args->city && $args->province_state && $args->postcode && $args->country)
    { //Don't bother including middlename if it doesn't matter if it is filled or not...
        $temp_arr = array($normname, $fulladdress);
        foreach($temp_arr as $value)
        {
            foreach($value as $values)
            {
                echo $values;
            }
        }
    } else {
        die ("Must enter all values excluding middlename.");
    }
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Well that seems to fix part of it, but now it only prints the FIRSTNAME and not all the info.

Comment: If you update the code, could you also update the sample you have?

Comment: Thanks your edit helped a ton. Actually one last question @Malovich , how would I make the script loop through the returned values?

At the point `echo $p1->create_people($p1);` ?

Comment: return the collected values as an array and assign it to a variable. foreach the array and echo them as you go.

Comment: `function echo_arguments{foreach(echo $this->create_people($this) as $values){echo $values;}} $p1=new people_handler();

$p1->firstname="John";$p1->middlename="Jonah";$p1->lastname="Jameson";
$p1->city="Lansing";$p1->province_state="Michigan";$p1->postcode="48876-4444";$p1->country="USA"; $p1->echo_arguments($p1);` just gives me my error handler die event for create_people, "Must enter all values excluding middlename."

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the self-reference problem (btw the `$args` is also not needed as this should be the self-reference), your loop structure is wrong.

```
$temp_arr=array($normname,$fulladdress);
foreach($temp_arr as $value)
{
   foreach($value as $values)
   {
       return $values;
   }
}
```

This will:

1. Loop through temp_arr, finding $normname as the first value
2. Treat $normname as an array and loop through it
3. Return the first value it finds in $normname
4. That concludes the function, everything else is not executed.

A function can only have *one* return value. If you need to return information on more than one thing, you need to return it as an array or as an object so that it is all wrapped up in one element.

At the moment I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish with your class, so unfortunately I can't help you with what you need to do.

Edit: You don't need to return anything in that case. Your class makes those variables accessible to all functions within the class already. With "new" you create an instance of the object, that is you create "a people_handler". This people_handler has properties about it, which you made public, so they can be set from outside the class (which may not be a great idea in a bigger project but seems fine for this). All functions which are part of the class (that is, inside it), can access what values these properties currently have for that certain people_handler by using the self-reference, `$this`:

```
class TestClass {
    public fullname; //a random "property"
    function echoFullname() {
        echo $this->fullname; //whatever fullname is at the moment for the TestClass object we are using
    }
}

$a = new TestClass(); //Create a TestClass object
$a->fullname = "Alex"; //make its name "Alex"

$b = new TestClass(); //Create another TestClass object
$b->fullname = "Carl"; //but let's name him Carl

$a->echoFullname(); //And now output the names
$b->echoFullname();
```

Obviously this has no practical use but hopefully illustrates how it works.As you can see, variable passing wasn't necessary at all.

Comment: I wish to return all the values that I enter into the function, because the information is going to be passed to other functions within the class. I am only trying to echo it for debugging purposes.

Comment: So is my return loop going to return each value to my other functions correctly, if not how should I update it so it does?

Comment: If you are trying to have it return all of the data that you entered, there are two ways. You can return an *array* of all the data and then `var_dump()` it instead of echo. Or you can return a *string* which contains all the data. For the former, you would remove the `foreach` and just do `return $temp_arr;`. For the latter, put the resulting string together in the loops like `$result_line .= $values; /*...*/ return $result_line;`

Answer (score 1):

at line 14:

```
    $fullname=array($firstname,$middlename,$lastname);
```

Probably should be:

```
    $fullname=array($this->firstname,$this->middlename,$this->lastname);
```

same one line 16:

```
    $fulladdress=array($city,$province_state,$postcode,$country);
```